# How to suppress output of exception while running unit tests in Clojure

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, leiningen

I am using leiningen for clojure, and I have a suite of Unit-tests that run when I run `lein test`.

I noticed that in some of the tests, we want to test exception handling scenarios and for that we throw an exception.
The problem is, it returns a full stack trace in command line which I often take for something bad happened, when it's really not.

Coming from the JS world, I saw that we can suppress exceptions which we want to mark it as suppressed in frameworks like jest, is there any option with leiningen or clojure for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite way is to use the [tupelo.test](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo) library as demonstrated in [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).  For example:

```clj
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest
  (is= 5 (+ 2 3))
  (throws? (/ 1 0)))
```

with result

```sh
-----------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.3    Java 15.0.2
-----------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core

Ran 2 tests containing 2 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

It will fail if the expression inside `throws?` does NOT throw an exception.  Otherwise it is a passing test.

This uses `try/catch` under the hood, which you could always do manually as well.

---

**If you really don't want to use a library**, you can do it in [clojure.test](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html).  You need to use syntax like:

```
(is (thrown? ArithmeticException (/ 1 0)))
```

However, beware that this feature is brittle and you get no warning if you make a mistake.  That is why I wrote the wrapper `tupelo.test/throws?` as it is easy and bulletproof.

Since the Tupelo library is open source, you could always copy the source code if you want:

```clj
(defmacro throws? 
  "Use (throws? ...) instead of (is (thrown? ...)) for clojure.test. Usage:
     (throws? (/ 1 0))                      ; catches any Throwable"
  [& forms]
  `(clojure.test/is
     (try
       ~@forms
       false ; fail if no exception thrown
       (catch Throwable dummy#
         true)))) ; if anything is thrown, test succeeds
```

So you can see that all the `throws?` macro does is wrap your code in a try/catch, then return either `true` or `false` to the standard `clojure.test/is` form.

Comment: This is nice! though I was looking for some solution/library on `clojure.test` as moving cost to this library will be huge

Comment: Not what I asked earlier, but if we are mocking functions in test, and want that mocked function to throw the exception, can we suppress it?

Comment: Mocking a function via `with-redefs` will not affect the `throws?` macro.

Comment: No, it's more like, I will mock the function to throw exception, I don't won't to assert to see if there is an exception or not, so I won't use `thrown`? and I want to test other things like maybe some variable got set or something got logged for the implementation's catch flow.